# How to Perform Outer Join in HQL / How to Use Outer Join Query in HQL

Tags: sql, hql, outer-join

**This is SQL Please Convert it in HQL**

```
SELECT * 
   FROM calendar_table
 LEFT OUTER JOIN fitness_parameter 
   ON calDate=RecordDate
WHERE  calDate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE() 
ORDER BY calDate DESC;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HQL right outer join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746332/hql-right-outer-join)

Comment: @ jruizaranguren: please write a HQL for above SQl query.Thank you in advance.

Comment: @jruizaranguren: IMHO, not duplicate because query of other question use a different outer join (property depends bu main property), instead here calDate and RecordDate haven't hierarchical link

Comment: Is there anyone to help me out..pls

Comment: @Simulant: thank u Gentleman thank u for editing my code.

Comment: Is there a foreign key relationship between the calendar table calDate column and the fitness_parameter RecordDate or not?

Comment: What is the data type of the date columns? Do they have a time component, or are they just dates?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research or effort. It is a blatant request for code.

Answer (score 1):

```
(select * from calendar_table
WHERE calDate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
) r left outer join fitness_parameter s on (r.calDate=s.RecordDate) ORDER BY r.calDate DESC;
```

Comment: A code-only answer: should be improved with some explanation to help posters learn.